# Access resource bundle from different plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

I have two plugins:

```
com.example.a
com.example.b
```

`com.example.a` contains the plugin.properties that I want to access from `com.example.b`.
When I'm calling the following in Plugin `com.example.b`, I get a `MissingResourceException`:

```
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "com.example.a",
                                                                Locale.getDefault() );
resourceBundle.getString( key );
```

This is obviously wrong, but I hope you get the point.

How can I access the localized strings of a properties file from another plugin?

Comment: hi, can you please post the full stacktrace following MissingResourceException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will load the plugin.properties or whatever is specified for the plugin in the 'Bundle-Localization' MANIFEST.MF header:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("com.example.a");
BundleContext bundleContext = bundle.getBundleContext();
ServiceReference<BundleLocalization> ref = bundleContext.getServiceReference(BundleLocalization.class);
BundleLocalization bundleLoc = bundleContext.getService(ref);
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = bundleLoc.getLocalization(bundle, Locale.getDefault().toString());
```